# Allow user to use tab in RichEditBox in a Windows 8 App?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Right now the tab function moves the focus to the next control, I want it so it just actually tab in the Text Box.

I noticed you cannot tab in the Windows 8 Mail app also....

Also is there a RichTextBox alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently (in the RTM release) there is no `AcceptsTab` like setting for [RichEditBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR227548) (it only has [AcceptsReturn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.acceptsreturn.aspx)) see also this [feature suggestion.](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2862272-add-an-acceptstab-property-to-richeditbox)

However you can subscribe on the `KeyDown` event of your `RichEditBox` where you can handle the tab key yourself:

```cs
private void RichEditBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab)
    {
        RichEditBox richEditBox = sender as RichEditBox;
        if (richEditBox  != null)
        {
            richEditBox.Document.Selection.TypeText("\t");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```