# UWP/WinRT: How to make the tab key behave as normal in a TextBox?

Tags: textbox, windows-runtime, c++-cx, uwp

By default, the Textbox doesn't insert tab characters. When you press Tab, it instead moves focus to the next element. When you press Ctrl-Tab, it inserts a tab character.

How can this behavior be fixed to act like people normally expect text boxes to behave, such that the Tab key inserts an indent using the tab character? Furthermore, how can Ctrl-Tab can be remapped to an alternative function?

For the first question of inserting a tab character, I can attach to the TextBox's KeyDown event and if the key pressed is Tab, then mark the event as handled to prevent the TextBox from losing focus, but how can I insert the Tab character?

When I attach to the Textbox's KeyDown event, pressing the Tab key never fires the listener at all if Ctrl is already held down. If I attach to the TextBox's KeyUp event, pressing the tab key does get picked up, but only after it has already inserted a tab into the TextBox. How can Ctrl-Tab be remapped without this unwanted behavior?

I'm working in C++/CX.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654213/allow-user-to-use-tab-in-richeditbox-in-a-windows-8-app

Comment: @sibbl Unfortunately, that approach doesn't work for a TextBox, because there is no equivalent that can be directly accessed as far as I can tell to the RichEditBox's Document text object model.

Comment: I'm doing the same as your answer now. Fun fact: [Ctrl-I inserts a Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045514/how-to-stop-control-i-from-inserting-a-tab-in-a-uwp-textbox-at-corewindow-scope). Don't know where this strange TextBox came from (see also [weird newline management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138047/textbox-text-substringtextbox-selectionstart-doesnt-work-because-selectedtext) in [`SelectedText`, `SelectionLength`, etc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f31f34ed-8751-4792-99d6-7c080582d899)), but I hope Microsoft comes to its senses & refactors it. /sigh

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is in the same situation, here is a solution I ended up developing. It is in my opinion shockingly ugly for how simple the problem is, and also rather unsatisfactory. If anyone has a better solution, I would love to hear about it.

The general idea is to override the KeyDown event for Tab to insert a '\t' character. It would be great to be able to override the KeyDown event for Ctrl+Tab as well, but that does not seem to be possible, as some sort of hardcoding on TextBox swallows up the Ctrl+Tab KeyDown event and it never even fires. Therefore, the KeyUp event for Ctrl+Tab is overridden.

```
KeyDown(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (e->Key == VirtualKey::Control) m_CtrlKeyPressed = true;
    else if (e->Key == VirtualKey::Tab) {
        // There is no need to test for if Ctrl is pressed here, since Ctrl-Tab appears to
        // be hardcoded into TextBox.
        // When Ctrl is pressed, a KeyDown event for Tab is never fired by TextBox.

        // Normally TextBox will try to give up focus when Tab is pressed - this prevents
        // that.
        e->Handled = true;

        // Platform::Strings support almost no operations, so we will need to cast the
        // TextBox's text into a wstring to insert.
        TextBox^ textBox = static_cast<TextBox^>(sender);
        std::wstring modifiedString(textBox->Text->Data());

        // SelectionStart works as current cursor position even when no text is selected.
        int cursorPosition = textBox->SelectionStart;

        // Unfortunately, casting into a wstring reveals Windows line-endings as \r\n,
        // which count as two characters now.
        // Therefore, every time we run into a line-ending our cursorPosition will become
        // off by one, so we need to compensate.
        int offsetDueToLineEndings = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cursorPosition + offsetDueToLineEndings; i++)
        {
            if (modifiedString[i] == '\r') offsetDueToLineEndings++;
        }
        modifiedString.insert(cursorPosition + offsetDueToLineEndings, 1, '\t');

        // Unfortunately, this text replacement wipes TextBox's built-in undo data.
        textBox->Text = ref new String(modifiedString.c_str());
        textBox->SelectionStart = cursorPosition + 1;
    }
}


KeyUp(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{   
    if (e->Key == VirtualKey::Control) m_CtrlKeyPressed = false;
    else if (m_CtrlKeyPressed)
    {
        if (e->Key == VirtualKey::Tab) {
            // See KeyDown for Tab for comments on this code.
            TextBox^ textBox = static_cast<TextBox^>(sender);
            std::wstring modifiedString(textBox->Text->Data());

            int cursorPosition = textBox->SelectionStart;

            int offsetDueToLineEndings = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cursorPosition + offsetDueToLineEndings; i++)
            {
                if (modifiedString[i] == '\r') offsetDueToLineEndings++;
            }
            modifiedString.erase(cursorPosition + offsetDueToLineEndings - 1, 1);

            textBox->Text = ref new String(modifiedString.c_str());
            textBox->SelectionStart = cursorPosition - 1;

            // Do something with Ctrl+Tab
        }
    }
}
```

A number of severe problems exist with this implementation.

For the simple Tab press:

- The insertion of a Tab causes the undo data for the TextBox to be wiped.

For the Ctrl+Tab press:

- If the user holds down Ctrl+Tab, multiple tabs will be inserted until he releases Tab.
- When triggering, for a split moment the tab is visible being created and deleted, which looks shoddy.
- The usage of Ctrl+Tab causes the undo data for the TextBox to be wiped.

The downsides probably mean this solution is unusable. Again, if there is a better solution, I would love to hear about it. At the least, maybe seeing the results of my approach can save someone else the trouble of implementing and discovering all of these problems themselves.

Comment: So looking back over, one change that I've done from what you've got (granted, it's in C#) is to edit what's in the TextBox's `SelectedText` rather than deal with the full `Text` property. Apologies if I'm missing something with your code, but I don't have to worry about undo wiping. There's lots of in-house extension code, but [here's what I'm doing for my first cut at this](http://pastebin.com/0xTLLh12).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue in WinUI3 and I wrote this to fix the issue when using **TextBox** controls:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handle TAB press so we don't switch focus to another control.
/// </summary>
void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            var selStart = tb.SelectionStart;
            var content = tb.Text;
            tb.Text = content.Insert(selStart, "\t");
            tb.SelectionStart = selStart + 1;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```